# Gradle - Could not find load main class

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, gradle.properties

I need to tune the JVM memory by help of Gradle. I've writen settings in the gradle.properties file:

> org.gradle.jvmargs=-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=60M

but it didn't work. Then I've done it manually in an IDEA (Run>Edit Configurations...) and wrote the settings for the needed class (in VM options: field) and it works. Can we do the same by help of Gradle?

I've tried to do:

> org.gradle.jvmargs=-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=60M test1.Test

but I got the error:

> Error: Could not find or load main class test1.Test

Comment: Do you want to configure the memory of the Gradle daemon, or your own (likely forked) application? Also, I'm not sure I understand what the question title has to do with the question body.

Comment: Added more detailes about the problem. I want to configure my own (likely forked).

Comment: How did you run your application? If you are running it via `java` command, then gradle is not involved at all and you cannot change anything by using gradle params.

Comment: Also from gradle documentation: `org.gradle.jvmargs` specifies the JVM arguments used for the Gradle Daemon (i.e. gradle itself, because its written on jvm languages) , not your application.

Comment: If you're executing your project via the `application` plugin then you can set the `applicationDefaultJvmArgs`. See example 3 here: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html

Comment: I did so, but it doesn't work:                                                                                  plugins {
    id 'application'
}

apply plugin: 'java'

application {
    applicationDefaultJvmArgs = ["-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=60M"]
}

Comment: Maybe I do sth wrong?

Comment: @scala231 how do you run your application?

Comment: By help of IDEA.

Comment: what is the actual command that is being invoked? In the `Run` window on very top you see the command, its greyed out and truncated, but if you click it will expand.

Comment: It runs via java command.

Comment: Have IntelliJ delegate to Gradle. You can create a Gradle run configuration that simply executes `run` (or whatever task you need to use to execute your application).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run your application via IDEa, it runs the application using `java ...` command and gradle is not involed at all, so whatever you put in `build.gradle` doesn't matter.

If you want to run your app via gradle, consider using [application plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html), which allows you to set jvm args. If you use Spring Boot use can use `bootRun` task and specify params in `jvmArgs` property.

Comment: @scala231 If my answer helped you, please accept it